# Cordova StatusBar Default Style Text Color White

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using Christophe Coenraets's [sample Angular app](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/11/sample-mobile-application-with-angularjs/) as a template to build out a simple angular app for Cordova.

I've added the [Cordova Status Bar plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) and built it into my app.

According to the docs if I call `StatusBar.styleDefault()` inside my `onDeviceReady` method I should get dark text on a translucent background.

My background is translucent, but my text remains white.

Inside my `onDeviceReady` method I have:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
},
```

As you can see in the image below, no love on the black text.  Any ideas on how to get black text?

[image: White Text]

Answer (score 1):

I am calling this from within app.js and it seems to be working the way you'd like.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the    keyboard
    // for form inputs)

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
         StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```